# Corrupt Binary Executable?

Tags: debian, executable, wkhtmltopdf

```
:/usr/local/bin# file wkhtmltopdf 
wkhtmltopdf: Mach-O executable i386
```

This file will not run.  I have tried removing and reinstalling with no success.   I have looked at the permissions (below) and they seem ok too:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  13817060 Aug  9 13:07 wkhtmltopdf
```

When I run wkhtmltopdf I get the error below:

```
wkhtmltopdf 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: confirm it , does this file have execution permission ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the executable format for Mac OS X, you need a binary compiled for linux to be able to run it.

Comment: sudo pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf (overwrite defaults with e.g. ARCHITECTURE=amd64 TO=/home/foo/bin)

Comment: I guess I need to change the ARCHITECTURE so it is debian?  I guess it it Mac by default?

Comment: might be, I haven't used exactly that piece of software myself. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Alexander is correct in why the binary you have won't run. It's an OS X binary and you can't 
run those on Linux systems. You need a Linux binary.

---

If you are running testing or unstable, just run `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` to install it using the packaging system.

You can also try these prepackaged versions from their website:

- http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_beta4-static-amd64.tar.bz2
- http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_beta4-static-i386.tar.bz2

Comment: apt-get can't find the package.  I'll try the manual approach!